# Sign in with Apple - Button customization

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, apple-sign-in

I have the custom policies working correctly with Apple Sign In but once I submitted to Apple for review they rejected my app because the button doesn't use the proper design/branding.

Is there a way to customize the "Sign in with Apple" button with a logo and colors?

From Apple:

> Your app uses Sign in with Apple as a login option but does not use Sign in with Apple button design, branding and/or user interface elements appropriately as described in the Sign in With Apple Human Interface Guidelines.

Comment: You're not allowed to do much with it. See the acceptable options laid out at https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sign-in-with-apple/overview/buttons/.

Comment: Did you managed to get this to work? I´m having problem with getting the apple logo to show up and can´t find where to add it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I was able to customize quite a lot including the button background image, which is the logo by using a custom page and css. I just followed this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-ui-customization

Just make sure to use at least one of their templates like Ocean Blue or Slate Gray. This you won't have to create new styles and images from scratch. Just modify as you desire.

Comment: I have read the tutorial but I can´t get it to work. How to one add the apple logo to the button?